# Dupla associação com sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Tenho a seguinte relação com o sequelize

```js
// Tasks.js

sequelize.models.tasks.belongsTo(sequelize.models.users, {
 foreignKey: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  field: 'ASSIGNEE',
  allowNull: true
 },
 as: 'assignee'
});

sequelize.models.tasks.belongsTo(sequelize.models.users, {
 foreignKey: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  field: 'REPORTER',
  allowNull: true
 },
 as: 'reporter'
});

// Users.js

sequelize.models.users.hasMany(sequelize.models.tasks, { as: 'assignee' });
sequelize.models.users.hasMany(sequelize.models.tasks, { as: 'reporter' });
```

Porém, o que eu preciso é que, na minha tabela de Tasks, tenha apenas 2 colunas com FK (ASSIGNEE e REPORTER). O problema é que o sequelize cria essas colunas, mas cria uma 'userId' também.

É possível fazer essa relação entre os mesmos models com 2 colunas diferentes?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que essa não seja a forma ideal para definir os relacionamentos, descrevendo a `foreignKey` nesse momento.

Os exemplos de Sequelize costumam fazer:

```js
const User = sequelize.define('User') // campo id é default

const Task = sequelize.define('Task', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING, // exemplo
  reporterId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field: 'REPORTER',
    allowNull: true
  },
  assigneeId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field: 'ASSIGNEE',
    allowNull: true
  }
})

Task.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'reporterId',
  as: 'Reporter'
})

Task.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'assigneeId',
  as: 'Assignee'
})
```

O que resulta na possibilidade de fazer a seguinte query:

```js
return Task.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'Reporter'
    },
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'Assignee'
    }
  ]
})
.then(tasksArray => {
  console.log(tasksArray[0])
  // { name: <teste>, Reporter: {id: <userId_1>}, Assignee: {id: <userId_2>}
})
```

Então, respondendo à pergunta, o Sequelize pode criar um campo default para o relacionamento **`Task.belongsTo(User)`** chamado justamente de **`userId`**. Para evitar isso é necessária a definição do campo no modelo do Task antes de estabelecer o relacionamento (vide meu exemplo).

Lembrando que só é necessário definir o relacionamento de `User.hasMany(Task)` se for realizar a query nesse sentido, funcionando da mesma forma que o exemplo acima.